Custom cell fracture pieces
I heard about the cell fracture feature, and it is quite interesting. however i want to know if i can set custom objects as pieces. for example, i could replace the default piece shape with lego blocks, or cubes, or something

No, that’s just not how cell fracture works. It cuts the mesh into cells along planes. If you want to make a mesh out of custom pieces though, I recommend you look into Geometry Nodes solutions with instancing the pieces on points distributed in a volume (such as shown in this YouTube tutorial), but the result will probably be only simple 1x1 bricks or randomly chosen pieces, not correct special bricks and such. For more precise LEGO models, you can find or build them on Mecabricks and then use their Blender add-on to import the LEGO models as separate bricks.
